# establish relationship between header and .cc file

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, header-files, undefined-reference

A few weeks ago I started learning c ++. At this time I must use functions declared and defined in header and .cc files. The problem is that when I include the header file in my code, I get a message saying that there are undefined functions. How to establish the link between the file h and the .cc?

In my code I have

```cpp
#include "CommSerialLinux.h"
```

The .h file has the following content (for obvious reasons it's just an excerpt)

```
typedef void (*CallBackFuncPtr)(CCommPacket *, PacketType);

class DYNAMIC_LINK CCommSerialLinux

{
public:

    CCommSerialLinux();
    virtual ~CCommSerialLinux();
    BOOL Open(const char *port);
    BOOL Close();
    BOOL IsOpen(){ return m_IsSerialPortOpened; }
    BOOL Receive();
    BOOL SendRaw(CWriteRawPacket *SendPacket);

    __u32 EncodePkt(CWriteRawPacket *SendPacket, __u8 *Data, int MaxSize);


    void RegisterCallBack(CallBackFuncPtr NewFuncPtr, PacketType RegisterType);


private://unimportant content

};
#endif
```

On the other hand, there is a file called CommSerialLinux.cc with the following content (extract)

```
void CCommSerialLinux::RegisterCallBack(CallBackFuncPtr NewFuncPtr, PacketType RegisterType)

{
    if(RegisterType < 0 || RegisterType > 255) return;
    m_CallBackFuncPtr[RegisterType] = NewFuncPtr;
    m_CallBackFuncReg[RegisterType] = TRUE;
}
```

when compiling I receive the following error:

> reference to `CCommSerialLinux::RegisterCallBack(void (*)(CCommPacket*, PacketType), PacketType)' sin definir

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile each of `.cc` files (which includes some header files - including repeat includes of headers included from elsewhere) into object code. This can be done by a single compilation command which also links the objects into an executable; or you can compile each `.cc` file separately, then link them all together.

When compiling, it's not a problem that some functions are undefined - they are expected to originate from other compiled objects and be found during linking.

(Since you did not specify exactly how you're trying to build your executable, I can't be much more specific.)

Comment: So far I only worked with a single file so I compiled: sudo g ++ main2.cpp -larmadillo (I'm using the armadillo library). Now, note that the "library" I should work with comes with a make file that has the following content:

####### Files
OBJECTS = obj / AckPacket.o obj / CommPacket.o obj / CommSerialLinux.o obj / GPSTelemPacket.o obj / StdTelemPacket.o obj / TranslatePacket.o obj / WriteRawPacket.o obj / Demo1.o
TARGET = Demo1

####### Build rules###

Comment: From what I understand the file named "demo" should be my code and the objects are where are the compilations of all other files that will be linked to my code?

Comment: @JuanRoa Why are you compiling as root?!

Comment: @melpomene although it has no relation to the question, copy and paste error since I was running as root because I am using the ttyS0 port of the raspberry pi